# Functional React Component with an argument in curly braces

Tags: reactjs

I recently came across this piece of code on a website

```
const List = ({ items }) => (
  <ul className="list">
    {items.map(item => <ListItem item={item} />)}
  </ul>
);
```

Why have they wrapped the items in curly braces and is it a prop

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is called a "destructuring". Actually, you're passing an object as an argument to the function, but the destructuring uses only the named properties of the object.

```js
const destructuring = ({ used }) => console.log(used);
    
const properties = {
  unused: 1,
  used: 2,
};

destructuring(properties); // 2
```

You can even use it for creating variables.

```js
const properties = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 21,
};

const { name, age } = properties;

console.log(name, age); // John Doe 21
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm a newbie to React, but I think yes, `items` is a prop, and passing `{items}` as an argument destructures the `props` object, and thus the function uses only the prop `items`, in order to simplify the code. This way you can use `items` in the functional component, instead of `props.items`. For example, I tested a similar situation in the following code.  Using destructuring looks like this:

```
const ListItem = ({content}) => (
  <li>{content}</li>
);
...
<ListItem key={index} content={content} />
```

Whereas if you used `props` it would look like this:

```
const ListItem = (props) => (
  <li>{props.content}</li>
);
...
<ListItem key={index} content={content} />
```

So for your example, using props would look like this:

```
const List = (props) => (
  <ul className="list">
    {props.items.map(item => <ListItem item={item} />)}
  </ul>
);
```

Meanwhile, destructuring allows you to simplify to `items`, rather than `props.items` which is what was being done in your original code:

```
const List = ({ items }) => (
  <ul className="list">
    {items.map(item => <ListItem item={item} />)}
  </ul>
);
```

Cheers!
--Omar